# A paradox related to computable reals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computability, fake-proofs

Let O be a computable ordering of all computable reals in ⟨0,1) (eg. first by length of programs computing them and then lexicographically). (it does not matter that they appear there more than one time).
It seems to be possible to produce a computable real not in this ordering by diagonal argument, using a deterministic algorithm to produce the non-matching digit.

What is the error in this reasoning?

Comment: Why doesn't it matter that they appear there more than one time? Say, real $r$ is computed by programs $P$ and $Q$ and $P<Q$ according the given order, and $s$ is computed by $S$ with $P<S<Q$. Then will be $r<s$ or $s<r$??

Comment: @Berci It only matters that all of them are represented there.

Comment: Why? Ah, maybe you automatically choose the *smallest* program (according to the given order)?

Comment: @Berci I think you misunderstood the question. The ordering was there only for the diagonal argument to work, but now I see that it is uncomputable (see Chris Eagle’s answer below).

Comment: The same paradox arose to me when reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3831684/168433) question. I thought that the solution probably was that there is no program enumerating the computable numbers and got it confirmed here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is that the computable ordering you want does not exist. You can easily order programs as you suggest, but since you can't computably determine which programs actually define real numbers, that doesn't help.

Comment: We could interpret everything our program produces as digits.

Comment: @kinokijuf: So what?

Comment: Ah, now I see. The program could hang (go into an infinite loop) before even printing anything.

Comment: So it is known/proven that there is no computable ordering of the computable reals?

Comment: @usul Yes. This question is _the proof_.