# A programmer’s doubts about countable vs uncountable infinity

Tags: computer-science, infinity, philosophy

(A short disclaimer: I'm not a mathematician, and I'm not trying to say anything is "wrong" about these famous proofs. I'm trying to get my bearings and maybe find where I can read more about a certain style of mathematical thinking.)

I’ve seen a few explanations of the proof that there are “more” reals than integers. Here’s [one on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uKGX1lt6ZY). It uses [Cantor’s diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument). This idea seems roughly equivalent to defining the difference between countable and uncountable infinity.

I still have doubts about this line of thinking. Maybe my confusion is more in the realm of philosophy than math. I have a background in computer programming, and I tend to think of math in terms of what we can make manifest in a running computer program. If something can exist only in thought, I don't value it as much.

Some steps of this proof (as I’ve seen them) go like: *"Do X an infinite number of times. When you're done, then do Y"*. Obviously such a thing can never "happen" in a material world where actions take finite time, nor can it "run" in a computer program.

This kind of infinity seems different from the one I first encountered in calculus, which *can* be used usefully in a computer program. For example, an "infinitesimal" number in calculus is like a finite number with an attached procedure to generate a smaller number, if needed. The statement "$dx$ is infinitely small" thus translates to "Here's $dx$, lets start with 0.001. If you want something smaller, ask." Again, as a computer programmer I'm used to dealing with values with attached procedures, so this feels natural to me.

If I imagine infinity in this "executable" way, as a source of numbers that can always provide another number, then this diagonal proof doesn't seem to work. You can always generate a new real number that isn't in your list of reals, but the source of integers can always "answer" by providing yet another integer, and the two infinite streams of numbers duel it out for as long as we want.

**Questions**

1. Can you define countable vs. uncountable infinity, or prove there are more reals than naturals,  without using one of these *un-executable* steps that say "do this forever, and when you're done ... “.
2. Is there is a school of mathematics that doesn't accept the proof, or that thinks as I describe above? If so, what it is called?

Comment: The ideas of constructivism and finitism seem related. And why would you downvote this question?

Comment: The school of mathematics that rejects "unexecutable" procedures is called constructivism. There the conclusion of the diagonal argument is reinterpreted: there is no executable procedure that enumerates all real numbers, see [cardinality in constructivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)).

Comment: The claim "the two infinite streams of numbers duel it out for as long as we want" seems to be the core of your objection, and I think you should expand on how exactly that would work. There is less symmetry here than it might seem. The diagonal argument is an *explicit program* that inputs a stream of reals and outputs a real not in the stream. How would you write a program to try to defeat it?

Comment: The philosophical mindset relevant here is probably more in the spirit of Zeno's paradoxes (where you _can_ do infinitely-many things is you "speed up toward the end", and where the _measure_ of "thing" is part of the problem), versus a halting-problem-like viewpoint, where every step takes one unit of time... The latter turns out not to be the best reflection of humans' "continuum" model of reality, etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I appear to be a constructivist. :) I will read more about that. @ChrisCulter I guess it depends how we are running this program. In the video, he shows a list of n reals in a 1-to-1 mapping with the integers 1 to n. He then creates the new real, not in the list. A program could map that to n+1. He'd create another, and the program could map that to n+2, etc. But if you asked the program a second time about a certain real number, it would need a _memory_, like a hashtable, to give the same answer again.

Comment: @RobN Never mind memory concerns. Assume you're granted whatever computing machinery you want. Are you claiming to have a description of a program that lists all real numbers?

Comment: Computationally, we cannot even show that there are infinite many primes. However, we can be absolutely sure that there is no largest prime. Do you accept "there are infinite many primes" ? Or do you reject the proof as "non-constructive" ?

Comment: @Peter Euclid's argument can be easily modified into a constructive one that generates a larger prime from those already generated.

Comment: @ChrisCulter I’m still churning on your question. I doubt I’ll get to the bottom of this soon. I can see that I don’t really understand real numbers. I know that sqrt(2) and π are examples (supposedly :) of reals that are not rational. But if a rational can get arbitrarily close to such a number, then I’m not sure how they are meaningfully different. Of course I can write a program that generates rationals.

Comment: @ChrisCulter I can also write a program that, for any real number you throw at it, will claim that an integer is mapped to that real number, and so it will act like a bijection between reals and integers. It just won’t be defined in a way that typical mathematical “functions” are defined. Because it will have an internal memory, and it will not know it advance what its mapping will be until you ask it! This is perfectly normal as “function” in a computer.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely recommend checking out constructivism for a broader look at what the sort of math you're advocating for looks like, but I think I can hopefully shed a bit of light on how to interpret Cantor's diagonal argument computationally.

**1. What is a real number computationally?**

**Computable reals:**
First we need to interpret real numbers as computations. We say that a real number $\alpha \in [0,1)$ is [*computable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) if there is a (terminating) algorithm $T$ that given a natural number $n$ as input produces $T(n)=\alpha_n$, the $n$th binary digit of $\alpha$. (We can assume that $\alpha$ is between $0$ and $1$, since the integer part of $\alpha$ can be represented by a natural number and a sign bit).

There are also many other variants that are all essentially equivalent. The idea is that we should be able to approximate the real number to within $\epsilon$ in finite time by a deterministic algorithm.

**Other reals:** Now, there are things that we might want to consider real numbers that cannot be represented by a finite, deterministic algorithm $T$. For example, if we are given a source of randomness, we could randomly output bits, and there will be no deterministic algorithm that would be guaranteed to replicate the output of the random bit producer for as long as we want. The probability of matching $n$ bits of the random bitstream is $1/2^n$ after all (assuming $P(0)=P(1)=1/2$).

**Representing arbitrary reals:** So hopefully we can agree that there should be other things we might want to consider real numbers. An "arbitrary" real number can be represented by an [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine) for its bits. If we want to use Turing machines as our computation model, an arbitrary real number can be thought of as giving our Turing machine another tape, on which we've written down the entire binary expansion of this real number. For our purposes, I prefer to work at a higher level than Turing machines, so I'll think of an oracle as a black-box function call that instantly returns with the correct answer. So an oracle for a real number's bits is just a function $\omega$ that takes a natural number $n$ and returns a bit $\omega(n)$ representing the $n$th bit of the binary expansion of the corresponding real number.

**2. Cantor's argument computationally**

How do we want to interpret Cantor's argument computationally?

> Assume for each natural number $n$ we have an oracle $\omega_n$ representing a real number.
> Then we can (computably) produce a real number from these oracles together with a proof  that the real number we have produced is different from any of the real numbers represented  by the oracles.

The algorithm is straightforward. We define $T(n) = 1-\omega_n(n)$. The proof that $T$ is different from all the $\omega_n$ is that $T(n)\ne \omega_n(n)$, so they can't represent the same real number. (Actually, we have to be careful, because rational numbers have two distinct binary expansions, so this isn't strictly true. We can fix this by working in a base other than 2, or by modifying more than one bit of the number, but that's more of a technical detail.)

**3. Interesting side note**

Note that even though the computable reals are countable, since there are at most countably many algorithms, the diagonal argument proves that the computable reals are *computably uncountable*. I mean this in the sense that the diagonal argument proves that no *computable* list of computable reals can be complete. I.e., if we can write down a procedure that enumerates procedures for computing reals, then Cantor's diagonal argument allows us to write down a computable real that cannot possibly be generated by our enumeration procedure.

Comment: I'm afraid your definition of computable real is wrong. You can approximate a computable real to any desired precision, but that doesn't mean you can reel off its binary digits. You may be able to compute a number to arbitrary precision, but still not know whether it is greater, less than, or equal to $\frac12$; and in this case you can't even compute its _first_ binary digit. (Otherwise, an excellent answer!)

Comment: @TonyK ah you're right. I'll have to edit and fix that tomorrow. I was trying to find a definition that would make Cantor's diagonal argument easy to state, but you're right, it's not equivalent.

Comment: @jgon In my answer I objected to the proof steps like "Do X an infinite number of times, and when you're done, ...". These "bit oracle tapes" for arbitrary reals seem like the same thing, no? The "tape" is infinite, and thus can't exist in the computer.

Comment: @RobN Right, they're a conceptual model. You're never using all of the tape, because moving the read head takes time, so it doesn't matter whether they're infinite or not. You can think of them on a real computer as any procedure that outputs a nonterminating stream of bits as you ask for them.

Although, I still have to fix my definition of computable real, so there are some issues with this answer and modeling real numbers as bitstreams. It's been really busy recently.